# @font-face doesn't work with FF4

Tags: css, firefox, font-face

I am using `@font-face` to embed some fonts and everything works just fine on *Chrome, Safari, etc*. For some reason it's not working with **FF4**. I looked all over and can't find anything. I found some stuff with issues relating to using a **CDN** but that doesn't apply to me. The website `thewell.newcoastmedia.com` and I'll add the code I am using. If it matters, I am using **WordPress**.

The CSS:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: LeagueGothicRegular;
    src: url('league_gothic-webfont.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
    src: url('league_gothic-webfont.eot?iefix') format('eot'), /* IE6-IE8 */
         url('league_gothic-webfont.woff') format('woff'), /* Modern Browsers */
         url('league_gothic-webfont.ttf')  format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
         url('league_gothic-webfont.svg#svgFontName') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

My .htaccess file:

```
# Use PHP5 Single php.ini as default
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php5s .php

<FilesMatch "\.(ttf|otf|eot|woff|font.css)$">
  <IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*thewell.newcoastmedia.com"
  </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>

AddType image/svg+xml svg svgz
AddEncoding gzip svgz
AddType application/vnd.ms-fontobject eot
AddType font/truetype ttf
AddType font/opentype otf

AddType application/x-font-woff woff
```

Comment: I'm not seeing any @font-face rules at http://thewell.newcoastmedia.com/ . Am I just looking at the wrong page?

Comment: As Boris said there doesn't appear to be any @font-face rules specified and the font (LeagueGothicRegular) isn't being referenced anywhere either, no rules or specification of usage for the font mean it won't work as the page doesn't have the data

Answer (score 0):

Well where is `svg` here?:

```
<FilesMatch "\.(ttf|otf|eot|woff|font.css)$">
```

I'm using the stylesheets from [Font Squirrel](http://www.fontsquirrel.com) and they work in all browsers.